# Is there a way to do hourly batched writes from Google Cloud Pub/Sub into Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to store IoT event data in Google Cloud Storage, which will be used as my data lake. But doing a PUT call for every event is too costly, therefore I want to append into a file, and then do a PUT call per hour. What is a way of doing this without losing data in case a node in my message processing service goes down?

Because if my processing service ACKs the message, the message will no longer be in Google Pub/Sub, but also not in Google Cloud Storage yet, and at that moment if that processing node goes down, I would have lost the data.

My desired usage is similar to this post that talks about using AWS Kinesis Firehose to batch messages before PUTing into S3, but even Kinesis Firehose's max batch interval is only 900 seconds (or 128MB):
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/persist-streaming-data-to-amazon-s3-using-amazon-kinesis-firehose-and-aws-lambda/

Comment: Do you get one Pub/Sub message per IoT event?  Would it be possible to extend the ack deadline for messages processed by a given node until you are ready to send the file?  Then if node dies, after the ack deadline expires the messages will be redelivered to another subscriber in your processing service.

There's still the problem that you can't ack all of the messages simultaneously (if you have sufficiently many messages), so you may get duplicate entries if the node dies after uploading but before acking?  You might be able to solve this with timestamps/GCS object naming.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continuously receive messages from your subscription, then you would need to hold off acking the messages until you have successfully written them to Google Cloud Storage. The latest client libraries in Google Cloud Pub/Sub will automatically extend the ack deadline of messages for you in the background if you haven't acked them.

Alternatively, what if you just start your subscriber every hour for some portion of time? Every hour, you could start up your subscriber, receive messages, batch them together, do a single write to Cloud Storage, and ack all of the messages. To determine when to stop your subscriber for the current batch, you could either keep it up for a certain length of time or you could monitor the [num_undelivered_messages attribute via Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#gcp-pubsub) to determine when you have consumed most of the outstanding messages.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't occur to me to just running it once per hour. That makes sense.